# How to get Apache Spark ML training score after each iteration

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

Is there any way to get evaluation score such as RMSE in case of regression and precision-recall after each iteration? 
For example, if I have this:
LogisticRegression lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8);

Can how can I get 10 scores as the max integration is set to 10?
Any pointer will be highly appreciated. 
I’m using Spark 2.4 in Java. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've trained, you have a `LogisticRegressionModel` (assume it's called `model`). `model.summary()` gives you `LogisticRegressionTrainingSummary` and `model.summary().objectiveHistory()` gets you an array of the losses at each step. I don't believe you can get precision/recall after each iteration.

Note too that there will not necessarily be `maxIter` iterations--the model may have converged before that.

Comment: Hoyland, thanks for your answer. This certainly helped. Do you know if summary() function is available in case of MultilayerPerceptronClassificationModel? Thank you.